# unable to mount hdd

Tags: mount, ntfs

I'm unable to restart Windows, it throws up an error. So I got to use Ubuntu and yet I am unable to mount the volume. It throws up the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/ubuntu/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted.
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 8):

Try `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3`

But it will be more safe to boot into the Windows safe mode and do a clean shutdown.

Comment: A clean shutdown never works for one of my HDDs, I have to do this.
Then I have to do a chkdsk on that HDD before I can use it in windows again.

Answer (score 2):

It's not letting you mount the windows partitions since it detects Windows is hibernated. You have two options. Boot up with windows and shut it down normally, but this seems no be impossible since Windows is not working.

You could also try to force a recheck of that partition:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda3
```

After that, restart the system. You should be able to access the partition under Ubuntu. And maybe you can also boot Windows (but that depends of which problem your Windows installation has).

Comment: I have similar problem with hdd mounting from usb and fsck is do the trick. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

one time i was getting this error for my linux system due to problem during booting a system. This probably get affected because the windows might not properly shutted down, due to which each partition got locked by windows filesystem. I tried doing properly shutting down the windows system, but it didn't work completely. Then i came across two working commands

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaXY
```

Then to mount the disk in read/write mode

```
$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdaXY
```

where XY is your partisan id like sda1, sda2...n.

```
$ man ntfsfix
```

> ntfsfix  is  a  utility  that fixes some common NTFS problems. 
>   ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some
>   fundamental. NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and
>   schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.
>   You may run ntfsfix on an NTFS volume if you think it was damaged by
>   Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `/etc/fstab` file and append `,ro` to the mount options for the NTFS drive. Mount the drive. Now you can remove the hibernation file like so `sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /path to mount point` Make sure /dev/sdb1 is the actual device on your system. Change /etc/fstab, like above, from `ro to rw`.

It should work after that. Or, you can go in the bios/uefi. turn off `fast boot`, boot up Windows, shut it down. and boot up Linux. That should work too.